# Prototype in javascripts

Tags: javascript, prototype

How would I get my XCount to go to 100.

xCount==100;

```
var x= 'insert code here';

for (xCount = 1; xCount < 100 && x == x.constructor; xCount++)
   x = x.constructor;
```

Comment: Would you mind to clarify your actual goal or the thing you do not understand?

Comment: So I think im trying to get into the forloop by making sure x==x.constructor; This leaves me with what to make X so that it is the equal to it's constructor. Should I make X an string?

Comment: That's not more clear at all... what do you mean equals to its constructor? What are you trying to build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` has got a method `constructor()`, but not a property `constructor`. By setting `x=x.constructor` in your loop you avoid the exit condition of the loop. But the loop has already "finished before it was started" (i.e. it never ran) because the condition was *not met when entering the loop*!

If you look at x.construcor with console.log(x.constructor) you get something like

```
function String() {
    [native code]
}
```

If you want the loop to run you must set

```
x=x.constructor
```

before the loop!

Comment: so can i do var x = String.constructor and also, is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Well, that would make `x==x.constructor` true but that also means that your loop will not even perform once since the termination condition is met: `xCount < 100 && x == x.constructor` - if one of those conditions is false the whole condition is false and the loop terminates before it has even started ...

Comment: Scrap that - I made a logical mistake! Yes, the loop should run! Both condition will be true for the first 99 loops ... Maybe you should try using `===`instead of `==` since this will not try any conversions!

Comment: Is there a more elegant way for me to write that? Without changing the for loop, is there something that String.constructor is equal to? I am very confused on prototypes in inheritance and whatnot.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this strange code anyway?

Comment: Ah, I just want the best way to implement it. I found out through trials and errors that if I put x=Function, it would work! Can you explain to me why?